# how to find match between a column and a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I recently posted a question which seems to not be very clear https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857329/how-to-make-a-threshold-for-a-given-data-frame and I could not delete it since had one answer. here I made a clear question 
I have a data frame like below

```
M<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(6L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 5L
), .Label = c("203797_at", "205217_at", "211488_s_at", "211900_x_at", 
"213959_s_at", "217077_s_at", "219884_at", "220473_s_at"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(c(8L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("202498_s_at", 
    "203313_s_at", "204407_at", "207022_s_at", "212030_at", "218566_s_at", 
    "220926_s_at", "222204_s_at"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(7L, 
    2L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("201368_at", "201502_s_at", 
    "202211_at", "202422_s_at", "206542_s_at", "212902_at", "215509_s_at", 
    "215716_s_at"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(2L, 4L, 
    7L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 8L), .Label = c("203736_s_at", "204442_x_at", 
    "205882_x_at", "207317_s_at", "208138_at", "213731_s_at", 
    "215743_at", "218513_at"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(7L, 
    5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 6L), .Label = c("202052_s_at", "203809_s_at", 
    "206319_s_at", "206590_x_at", "208382_s_at", "216133_at", 
    "219736_at", "221818_at"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I have a column called T

```
T<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(5L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 3L
), .Label = c("203797_at", "205217_at", "211488_s_at", "211900_x_at", 
"213959_s_at", "217077_s_at", "219884_at", "220473_s_at"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", row.names = c(8L, 
4L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to check whether the first character of T is in the first column of M, if it is then 1 if it is not then zero.

```
# empty matrix with the same size az M 
output <- matrix (0,nrow(M),ncol(M))
```

The output should look like this

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    0    0    0    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0    0
[5,]    1    0    0    0    0
[6,]    1    0    0    0    0
[7,]    1    0    0    0    0
[8,]    1    0    0    0    0
```

If a character exist 1, if not zero

Comment: Another option is `mapply('%in%', M, list(T$V1)) + 0L`

Comment: What does it mean "the first charter of `T`"? All the answers here only checked if each element in`T` is present within `M`. No one compared the first character....

Comment: @David Arenburg if you know a better way, go ahead , I would love to see it

Comment: I said that I don't understand the question. What does "the first charter of T" means?

Comment: @David Arenburg T consists of 8 observation which will either exist in M or not, if exist then 1 if not then 0

Comment: So why are you calling an observation a character? Character means for example `a`. If you want to compare the first character of a string it means you want to compare lets say the `a` out of an `apple`. Also, why are you saying "first" if want to compare all `T` column to `M` (not just the first observation)?

Comment: @David Arenburg  my bad, each time one of the observation is checked for all observation in first column of M , then second observation of T should be checked to all observation of M then third and so on (observation is for example  entire 203797_at )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
> apply(M, 2, function(col)as.numeric(col%in%t(T)))

     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
[1,]  1  0  0  0  0
[2,]  1  0  0  0  0
[3,]  1  0  0  0  0
[4,]  1  0  0  0  0
[5,]  1  0  0  0  0
[6,]  1  0  0  0  0
[7,]  1  0  0  0  0
[8,]  1  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: I liked your solution

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty, but it works...

```
sapply(1:ncol(M),function(i) sapply(T,function(t) t %in% M[,i]))*1
```

Drop the '*1' to get a logical matrix.

Comment: I did't think of the `*1`! A shorter version could be `apply(M, 2, \`%in%\`, t(T))*1`

Comment: @PeterK I liked your solution